# How to show tab panel on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, tabs

Hello friends I found w3 tab script I used this in my project it perfectly work on my page but I want this tabs in two different panels in single page, two tabs panel not work perfectly only one tab panel works fines. following is code snippet

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
ul.tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="tabs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">

      <ul class="tab modal-tab">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Delhi')" id="defaultOpen">Delhi</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'NewYork')">New York</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="Delhi" class="tabcontent" style="display:block;">
        <h3>OrderDelivered</h3>
        <p>Delhi is the capital of India.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="NewYork" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>OrderFailed</h3>
        <p>New York is the city of America.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want this both of tab panel work fine not only one at a time

Comment: two tabs work perfectly doesnt on my page at a time one tab panel fine not only one :)

Comment: what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: as u see in my code snippet only one tab panel works like first panel is london, paris, tokyo and sencond panel is delhi or newyork if click on delhi which is second tab panel it show delhi tab content but hide frist tab contents or if i click on any first tab content which is london, paris or tokoy then my second tab content hide, I want that both panel work perfectly on same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added another specific class for the tab content,
Added another constructor for the functions, and hide the tabs for only clicked tab panel, not all tab panel of the html.

```js
 function openCity(evt, cityName, tabContent, tabContentLink) {
  var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName(tabContent);
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
    tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName(tabContentLink);
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
ul.tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks tabcontent-link-1" onclick="openCity(event, 'London', 'tabcontent-1', 'tabcontent-link-1')" id="defaultOpen">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks tabcontent-link-1" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris', 'tabcontent-1', 'tabcontent-link-1')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks tabcontent-link-1" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo', 'tabcontent-1', 'tabcontent-link-1')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="London" class="tabcontent tabcontent-1">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent tabcontent-1">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent tabcontent-1">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>

<br><br>

<div id="tabs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">

      <ul class="tab modal-tab">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks tabcontent-link-2" onclick="openCity(event, 'Delhi','tabcontent-2', 'tabcontent-link-2')" id="defaultOpen">Delhi</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks tabcontent-link-2" onclick="openCity(event, 'NewYork', 'tabcontent-2', 'tabcontent-link-2')">New York</a></li>
      </ul>

      <div id="Delhi" class="tabcontent tabcontent-2" style="display:block;">
        <h3>OrderDelivered</h3>
        <p>Delhi is the capital of India.</p>
      </div> 
      <div id="NewYork" class="tabcontent  tabcontent-2">
        <h3>OrderFailed</h3>
        <p>New York is the city of America.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated (fixed menu tab highlight issue)

Comment: very thanks full to you for this help, can you help me little more, in your code snippet in second tab panel active tab is not highlighted as first tab, how i highlight this to.

Comment: I have updated the code as what you need. Added new class for links & added new parameter for the function.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tablinks;
  $(this).parents().children('.tablinks').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $('#'+cityName).parents('.tab-container').children('.tabcontent').removeClass('active');
  $('#'+cityName).addClass('active');
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
ul.tab {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Float the list items side by side */
ul.tab li {float: left;}

/* Style the links inside the list items */
ul.tab li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of links on hover */
ul.tab li a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
ul.tab li a:focus, .tablinks.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
  display: none;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.tabcontent.active{
  display:block; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'London')" id="defaultOpen">London</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Paris')">Paris</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tokyo')">Tokyo</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-container">
<div id="London" class="tabcontent active">
  <h3>London</h3>
  <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
</div>

<div id="Paris" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Paris</h3>
  <p>Paris is the capital of France.</p>
</div>

<div id="Tokyo" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Tokyo</h3>
  <p>Tokyo is the capital of Japan.</p>
</div>
</div>
<br><br>

<div id="tabs">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12" style="padding:0px;">

      <ul class="tab modal-tab">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks active" onclick="openCity(event, 'Delhi')" id="defaultOpen">Delhi</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'NewYork')">New York</a></li>
      </ul>
    <div class="tab-container">
      <div id="Delhi" class="tabcontent active">
        <h3>OrderDelivered</h3>
        <p>Delhi is the capital of India.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="NewYork" class="tabcontent">
        <h3>OrderFailed</h3>
        <p>New York is the city of America.</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

with jquery you can use this method